# MVC3 Lazy Model Binding/Loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have the standard 'RequiredIf' attribute for some Conditional-Validation.
My form and Model are fairly large, the model has 63 properties and most of which are validated.

Anyway, I have an issue where my Model is getting loaded in *while* my validation is executing.
If i put a breakpoint on the first line of code inside the 'RequiredIf' 'IsValid' method, I can see that my Model has a lot of null values.  When I press F5 (to continue onto the validation of the next property), there are still lots of nulls.  If i press F5 about 5 more times the model magically fills with the data I posted.

My first 5-6 validations are getting screwed up because of this.  Anyone know anything about how the models are being loaded?  I am not using custom model binding.

Comment: Are you eager loading all of the entity relationships?  Or are these properties just primitive types?

Comment: These are all primitive types.  Most that are loading in are strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was the completely 'override' the standard model binding.  Create you own model binder, load in the whole model manually, then afterwards execute all of your model validation.  I'm still convinced that there is *some* way to just say "Hey, load in the whole model before validating" in this standard Model Binder, but I had to make my own for now.

Answer (score 1):

I would redesign your page and model and split data model and view in several small models maybe using several partial views.
This way you could manage your model in a better way. Imagine writing tests for that Model. 63 properties is too much and probably you need to address that or else it sounds you will run into problems later on.

Comment: I don't disagree with this, but redesigning someone else's code at the stage in the project isn't an option. :(